# Laravel: how to run migration to add a field to a pivot table and insert a value if the pivot exists

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have two pivot tables that contains *bookings* for `attendees` and `programs`. Each record contains the `attendee_id` and `program_id` of a *booking*.
If there is a record entry i.e. *booking* that means that the attendee is *registered*.

I want to migrate my table so that there is a field `registered` and `waitlisted`. Like so.

```
  public function up()
  {
    //
    Schema::table('bookings', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
      $table->increments('id');
      $table->boolean('registered');
      $table->boolean('waitlisted');
    });
    Schema::table('prog_bookings', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
      $table->increments('id');
      $table->boolean('registered');
      $table->boolean('waitlisted');
    });
  }
```

But to complete the migration, I need to set `registered` to be `1` if the `booking` previously existed in my database (there is a record in the pivot table). How do I do that?

Comment: There is something wrong in the explanation of the issue. I think you will need to clarify wich one is the pivot. Also just updating every existing row would satisfy what you require here because you have said that 'If there is a record entry' then it's registered, right?

Comment: yes sorry they are both pivot tables. I have updated the question. yes I guess updating every existing row would satisfy...I am not sure how to do that in the migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migrations are for setting up database tables and schemas, I think it would be better to leave that separated from generating and filling the values in side the table.

I suggest you use a script to do the job of setting `registered` to `1`. [Seeding](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/seeding) is a convenient component for database scripts in Laravel. For example:

```
# AttendeeRegisteredSeeder.php

public function run()
{
    foreach (Attenndee::all() as $attendee) {
        foreach ($attendee->programs as $program) {
            $program->pivot->registered = 1;
            $program->pivot->save();
        }
    }

}
```

After you completed the seeder script, run the artisan command:

```
php artisan db:seed --class=AttendeeRegisteredSeeder
```

This will only run the specified seeder class, which I think is what you want in your case.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes this helps, Thanks. 
It seemed to me that the migration would be the right place for the script because I was thinking of the entire change as a ""migration""